# I have made a function that encrypt a password, how can I reverse it so that I can get the real password after it was encrypted

Tags: encryption

This is my code for encryption, and I need to reverse this function:

```
public String encryptPassword(String input) {
    String encPass = null;
    if (input == null) return null;

    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(input.getBytes(), 0, input.length());
        encPass = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encPass;
}
```

Comment: MD5 is not a suitable hashing algorithm for passwords - it is susceptible to brute-force attacks. Consider Bcrypt instead.

Answer (score 1):

The MD5 Hash algorithm is not reversible, so MD5 decrypt in not possible. Some websites may offer to decrypt but they are dirty hack as they store and match against bulk set of passwords' MD5 encryptions.

Answer (score 1):

You have hashed the password, not encrypted it.  Hashes are designed to be irreversible, so you will not be able to recover the original password from the hash.  What you do is to take the password the user enters and MD5 hash that, then compare the hashes.  If they match then the user entered the right password.  If they do not match then the user entered the wrong password.

You might also want to look at [adding salt](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/) before you hash passwords for extra security.  Though that means you will have to store the salt for each user as well as their hashed password.

Comment: It is worth noting that MD5 is not suitable for passwords anyway - it is too fast.